# PhoneGap/Kendo UI app works fine on iPhone and Android but hangs on Blackberry OS 6 device without firing any errors

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui

My app doesn't seem to be initialising properly in Blackberry but also doesn't fire any errors. I've got a fairly simple app that I've built using Kendo UI and PhoneGap. It works fine on Android and iPhone and in the Ripple debugging sims for Blackberry.

However, I have a Torch device and when I launch the app on the device it gets to the opening screen and hangs there. The app is tabbed and when I try to click the tabs it just sticks on the first one with a blank frame where the rest of the app should be:

[image]

Using PhoneGap Build's debugging console and the console on the device itself, there don't seem to be any errors firing. Has anyone else encountered this, any ideas? I've asked this question to the PhoneGap support guys and they suggested I see if anyone on this side of the fence might be able to help.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewport in PhoneGap for BB6 is kind of bugged and the application in it can't specify height: 100%. This issue should be worked around in newer releases of Kendo UI Mobile, can you try if you can reproduce it with Q3 (released last week)?

Comment: That worked, thanks! The only problem I seem to be having now is that the icons on the tabstrip have stopped working. So it's two steps forward, one step back!

Comment: Do they work on BB7? When you upgraded, did you also copy the images subfolder that should contain the two icon fonts needed for the icons?